# Communicating with the Integration Service in Informatica wokflow monitor issue

Tags: informatica-powercenter

In workflow Monitor I tried to connect with Integration Service. But it is showing communicating with Integration service, upto 180 seconds. After that it was disconnected. Other components are connecting without any issues only monitor this issue is happening. Please advise on this and provide solutions for this issue.

Thanks
Viswa S

Comment: This happens mostly when client cant keep continuous connection to server. Are you having this for the first time after installation etc.? if no, are you facing this issue sometimes or always? See if your client can ping the server and you configured client correctly and your integration service is up and running without any issue. Also try form another server etc.

Comment: Hi Kaushik, Yes after installation I am getting this first time. And I am getting this sometimes only. I could ping the server. Everything is up to live while trying to connect it is saying COMMUNICATING error.

Comment: if you get it sometimes - this means connection is getting dropped sometimes from client machine to server. This happens when you have slow internet or slow server. check from some client where you have good connectivity.